# How to read a list of values into a data table in a sandbox?

Tags: r, import

I have a list of data. It's all a single column, each row is a comment from a post asking for book recommendations. Here's an example, containing the first 2 entries:

```
"My recommendations from books I read this year:<p>Bad Blood : Man, this book really does read like a Hollywood movie screenplay. The rise and fall of Theranos, documented through interviews with hundreds of ex-employees by the very author who came up with the first expose of Theranos. Truly shows the flaws in the &quot;fake it before you make it&quot; mindset and how we glorify &quot;geniuses&quot;.<p>Shoe Dog : Biography of the founder of Nike. Really liked how it&#x27;s not just a book glorifying the story of Nike, but tells the tale of how much effort, balance and even pure luck went into making the company the household name it is today.<p>Master Algorithm : It&#x27;s a book about the different fields of Machine learning (from Bayesian to Genetic evolution algos) and talks about the pros and cons of each and how these can play together to create a &quot;master algorithm&quot; for learning. It&#x27;s a good primer for people entering the field and while it&#x27;s not a DIY, it shows the scope of the problem of learning as a whole.<p>Three Body Problem: Finally, after years of people telling me to read this (on HN and off), I read the trilogy (Remembrance of Earth&#x27;s Past), and I must say, the series does live up to the hype. Not only is it fast paced and deeply philosophical, but it&#x27;s presented in a format very accessible to casual readers as well (unlike many hard sci-fi books which seem to revel in complexity). If I had to describe this series in a single line, it&#x27;s &quot;What would happen if China was the country that made first contact with an alien race?&quot;","A selection:<p>Sapiens (Yuval Noah Harari, 2014 [English]) - A bit late to the party on this one. Mostly enjoyed it, especially the early ancient history stuff, but I felt it got a bit contrived in the middle - like the author was forcing it. Overall a good read though.<p>How to Invent Everything (Ryan North, 2018) - First book I&#x27;ve pre-ordered in a long time. A look at the history of civilization and technology through a comedic lens. Pretty funny and enjoyable.<p>The Rise of Theodore Roosevelt (Edmund Morris, 1979) - Randomly happened across this book while browsing a used bookstore for some stuff to read on a summer vacation. Loved it. It&#x27;s big, but reads pretty quick for a biography. I&#x27;ve been a fan of TR since I first really learned about him in High School and I would recommend this for anyone interested in TR&#x2F;The West&#x2F;Americana.<p>Jaws (Peter Benchley, 1974) - Quite a bit darker than the movie.<p>Sharp Objects (Gillian Flynn, 2006) - I enjoyed Gone Girl (book and film) so I wanted to read this before the HBO series. To be honest...not my cup of tea. It was <i>okay</i>.<p>The Art of Racing in the Rain (Garth Stein, 2008) - Made me cry on an airplane. Thankfully my coworkers were on a different flight."
```

*(Notice, comments are separated by `","`)*

I'm trying to load this list into a data table in [an R sandbox](http://hackme.rapporter.net/) (rapporter.net). But because of browser security, I can't load a local file ([`fread`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-intro.html), [`read.table`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/utils/versions/3.5.2/topics/read.table)).

***How can I read raw data into a data table in R?***

Comment: fread can accept strings

Comment: OK, how do I get many strings in there? `dt <= fread(c("thing 1","thing 2"))` gives me `object 'fread' not found`.

Comment: Maybe import `fread` using `library(data.table)` first? Also try `<-` rather than `<=`. And you don't need the `c()`, just a single string that will be interpreted as if it was the raw contents of a csv file (so using commas and newlines (\n) as separators).

Comment: From data.table documentation: *Input:* Either the file name to read (containing no \n character) or the input itself as a string (containing at least one \n), see examples. In both cases, a length 1 character string. E.g. `fread("A,B\n1,2\n3,4")`

Comment: Not sure if this is a proper data frame having the same number of columns for each observation, so `read.csv` etc might not be the best choice even outside of the sandbox environment -- anyway, using `strsplit` etc should work.